# Error - FIXME: Implement XCBuild support for macros in overriding parameters with condition sets

Tags: ios, cordova, macos-catalina, cordova-cli

When running command `cordova run ios --device`, I am getting the following error:

```
FIXME: Implement XCBuild support for macros in overriding parameters with condition sets:

        CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*] = iPhone Developer
Error: Error code 1 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/myUser/Documents/demo-app/App/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,HelloCordova.xcworkspace,-scheme,HelloCordova,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,HelloCordova.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/myUser/Documents/demo-app/App/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/myUser/Documents/demo-app/App/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

The closest that I could google suggested either removing, then adding the platform again like so:

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

... or changing the `build-release.xcconfig` file reference from `iPhone Distribution` to `iPhone Developer` for both the "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY" and "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" values.

I've tried both but still end up with the same error.

**I'm running on the following:**

- Mac OSX: Catalina
- cordova version: 6.5.0

  - ios 4.3.1
- Xcode version: 11.2.1
- npm version: 6.13.6

Also, I verified that the device is attached using `cordova run --list`.  The device is an iPhone 11 Pro running iOS 13.3.1.

Thanks, in advance to anyone who has some insight into this.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode -> File -> Workspace Settings -> and change build settings (select legacy build settings from drop down):

[image: shown in image]